# How to remove direct product url in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to remove direct product url from magento?
for example

Instead of http://example.com/product1.html 
All product url should have category name in path.

Like http://example.com/category-name/product1.html

> Note: I dont want to access product with direct link. I m aware that
>   we can add category path in product url with enabling below settings.

go to `Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"`

Comment: if you searching and in search listing page if you click on any product then you not have other option except direct url for receptive product. and in magento one product can be assign to multiple category so which category you will need in url.

Comment: True, Agree to your point. But I guess we can change the product url in search page with category.In my case one product will assign to one category only

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set SEO option in admin for this

```
Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs -> Yes
```

**Edit**

I think you can use postdispatch event for the same

```
lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php 
controller_action_postdispatch
```

You can check the action called and based on that you can redirect product to path with contain category level. To get the product action and check product you can use

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$request = $event->getControllerAction()->getRequest();
$request->getFullActionName() // need to check if action is 'catalog_product_view'
```

You can get current product from registry object.

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh. Nice to hear from you. but actual I dont want to redirect customer from url. I dont want to generate a direct product url in system.

Comment: I understand...In magento product URL created by URL_Rewrite concepts where system adding category path and direct URL to url rewrite table. And in system you can have product without any category assigned. so either in your case if any product URL open directly you can sent it to no route. It oblivious you can't restrict customers to prevent using direct URL.

Comment: Okay, We can prevent them to using direct url. if we not generated direct url in system.